# Set Devart's Code Compare as custom diff & merge tool in Sourcetree?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, devart, codecompare

How to add  Devart's Code Compare as custom diff & merge tool within Sourcetree?

Comment: I take it `Code Compare` is not one of the built-in options for setting an external merge tool the way `Beyond Compare` is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I modified my `C:\Users\[User Name]\.gitconfig` file by adding this like Alex suggested:

```
[difftool "codecompare"]
cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\codecompare.exe' -W \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" 
renames = true

[diff]
tool = codecompare
guitool = codecompare

[mergetool "codecompare"]
cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\codemerge.exe' -MF=\"$LOCAL\" -TF=\"$REMOTE\" -BF=\"$BASE\" -RF=\"$MERGED\"
trustExitCode = true

[mergetool]
keepBackup = false

[merge]
tool = codecompare
guitool = codecompare
```

Then I changed my SourceTree `Tools -> Options -> Diff` to System Default.

After that my `Code Compare` started running correctly inside Visual Studio which is awesome.

Hope it helps!

[Code compare integration with source control systems](https://www.devart.com/codecompare/docs/index.html?vcs_integration.htm)

Answer (score 8):

In SourceTree open Tools > Options > Tab: Diff.

On panel External Diff / Merge put the following data:

External Diff Tool: Custom
Diff Command: `C:/Program Files/Devart/Code Compare/CodeCompare.exe`
Arguments: `$LOCAL $REMOTE`

Merge Tool: Custom
Merge Command: `C:/Program Files/Devart/Code Compare/CodeMerge.exe`
Arguments:`-MF "$LOCAL" -TF "$REMOTE" -BF "$BASE" -RF "$MERGED"`

[image: teste]

Comment: I have not delved into it but according to Devart it should be `-W "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"` for CodeCompare.exe

Comment: LosManos is right... it should have a -W in front of the "Diff Command" arguments.

Answer (score 2):

To integrate Code Compare with Sourcetree add the following lines to the `c:\Users\[User Name]\.gitconfig` file:

```
[difftool "codecompare"]
cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\codecompare.exe' -W \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" 
renames = true

[diff]
tool = codecompare
guitool = codecompare

[mergetool "codecompare"]
cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\codemerge.exe' -MF=\"$LOCAL\" -TF=\"$REMOTE\" -BF=\"$BASE\" -RF=\"$MERGED\"
trustExitCode = true

[mergetool]
keepBackup = false

[merge]
tool = codecompare
guitool = codecompare
```

Now git difftool will work properly from both command line and Sourcetree.

Note: you need select 'System Default' option in Sourcetree options.

[Git Integration](https://www.devart.com/codecompare/docs/git_integration.htm)

Comment: Couldn't get this working until I saw your note about setting Sourcetree's option to "System Default", thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: Win10, SourceTree 2.1.110, Code Compare 4.2.236

- SourceTree>Tools>Options>External Diff
- Diff: Tool->Custom;

  - Command: `c:\Program Files\Devart\Code Compare\CodeCompare.exe`
  - Arg: `$LOCAL $REMOTE`
- Merge: Tool->Custom

  - Command: `c:\Program Files\Devart\Code Compare\CodeMerge.exe`
  - Arg: `-MF=\"$LOCAL\" -TF=\"$REMOTE\" -BF=\"$BASE\" -RF=\"$MERGED\"`

> Keep in mind that 3-way merge is only available at Code-Compare PRO
>   https://www.devart.com/codecompare/featurematrix.html

Answer (score -1):

Check Devart Code Compare help file section on 'Version Control System Integration'. There is a topic for GIT.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.